# how to set unique primary key for all table in same database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

how to set an unique primary key to all the table of database?
for example i don't wanted to repeat any primary key of different table.

```
table A:
----------
id | name
----------
1  | aaa
3  | bbb
5  | ccc

table B:
-------------
id | surname
-------------
7  | ddd
2  | eee
9  | fff

table C:
-------------
id | nickname
-------------
4  | ggg
6  | hhh
8  | iii
```

all `id` are `primary key` and `auto_increment`.
All the data is entered dynamically.I am using `MYSQL` in `PHPMYADMIN`.

Comment: If you want to insert `id` through query (by removing `auto_increment`) then it is possible.

Comment: thats the problem...user will only insert his/her name...

Comment: Yes why not. User will not need to add `ID` it will be added automatically by query. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16494803/1369235).

Comment: And why do you need this (on 81 tables)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add a new table to your schema called `ID_Table` that will have only one numeric column called `current_id` with default value of 0 ,when adding a new row to any other table of the schema you have to call a select on the ID_Table returning `ID_Table.current_id + 1` as new id value.
Then updating ID_Table must be done

```
Update ID_Tableset ID_Table.current_id = ID_Table.current_id + 1
```

the `GetNewId` function could be implemented by
locking the ID_Table 
Updating ID_Table
returning NewID

something like this (I have used Oracle syntax)

```
create table ID_Table(
   current_id number
); 

Insert into ID_Table values(0);

CREATE OR REPLACE Function GetNewId RETURN number is
  new_id    ID_Table.current_id%type;
  row_count number;
begin
  select nvl(ID_Table.current_id, 0) + 1
    INTO new_id
    FROM ID_Table
     for update;
  update ID_Table set ID_Table.Current_Id = new_id;
  commit;

  RETURN new_id;
end GetNewId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same sequence as the id generator for each inserted row, regardless of the table.  Assuming you're using a DB that allows a sequence to be named as the id generator for the field.

This looks like it will do what you want in MySQL: http://devzone.zend.com/1786/mysql-sequence-generator/

Comment: Just saw the edit.  It doesn't look like MySQL allows for named sequences.... are you using Hibernate or another OR framework?  If so, you could manage it within there instead of in the RBDMS

Comment: Maybe this will help define a named sequence to share across tables, instead of using autoIncrement on the table: http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/simulating-sequences-in-mysql/

Comment: This also looks like what you want: http://devzone.zend.com/1786/mysql-sequence-generator/

Answer (score 1):

You can get maximum `ID` from all three tables then add it in your insert query. But you have to remove the `auto_increment` attribute.

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT MAX(ID)+1, 'jjj'
  FROM
      (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM TableA
       UNION
       SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM TableB
       UNION
       SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM TableC
      ) A;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d3f4/1)

Comment: hi.. your answer is ok with this 3 table example but i have 81 table. ..i can't apply this insert query all the time...

Answer (score 0):

Look at using Sequence. I'm not sure what DB you are using. Postgresql and Oracle have sequence that you can share between tables.

Comment: hi.. can u plz tell me how to use same sequence for primary key of different table in `MYSQL`...